# how to call parent function from retryWhen angular2

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I am trying to execute a function from retryWhen and after that call parent function when retryWhen is finished. How can I do that?

```
getStatuses(statusesType: string[]): Observable<IStatus[]> {

        let body = JSON.stringify({ "StatusesType": statusesType});
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + localStorage.getItem("access_token");
        headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });

        return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + '/statuses/statusesList', body, options)
            .retryWhen(error => this.refreshToken())
            .map((res: Response) => {
                this.statusesrecieved = res.json();
                return this.inspections;
            });
    }
```

I want to call getStatuses() function again after executing refreshToken() in retryWhen. Help is appreciated

I also tried with retry like this which is not working either.

```
 return this.http.post(this._baseUrl + '/statuses/statusesList', body, options)
                .retryWhen(error => this.refreshToken())
                .map((res: Response) => {
                    this.statusesrecieved = res.json();
                    return this.inspections;
                }).retry(5);
        }
```

Here is my refreshToken function

```
refreshToken(): Observable<any> {
        console.log("refreshing token");

        let body: string = 'grant_type=refresh_token&refresh_token=' + localStorage.getItem("refresh_token");
        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });


        return Observable.create(
            (observer: Observer<any>) => {
                this.http.post('https://fedqa.test.com/as/token.oauth2', body, options)
                    .map(res => res.json()).subscribe(
                    (data) => {

                        localStorage.removeItem("access_token");
                        localStorage.removeItem("refresh_token");
                        localStorage.setItem("access_token", data.access_token);
                        localStorage.setItem("refresh_token", data.refresh_token);
                        localStorage.setItem("token_type", data.token_type);
                        localStorage.setItem("expires_in", data.expires_in);
                    },
                    (error) => {

                        Observable.throw(error);
                    }
                    );
            });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming:

1. Assuming `this.refreshToken()` async and returns an Observable that completes once its done.
2. `this.refreshToken()` updates as a side effect and that it will be updated once the Observable completes.

You could use [`concat`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-concat) takes an observable that is subscribes to after the previous one completes(!!).

`getStatuses()` will immidiately look up the token in local storage so it cannot be used directly in `concat`, it has to trigger after `this.refreshToken` is finished, [`Observable.defer`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-defer) comes to mind:

```
...
.retryWhen(
  errors => this.refreshToken()
    .concat(Observable.defer(() => getStatuses(statusesType)))
)
```

While this could work for you I see potential infinite recursion happen. You might also want to check out [`retry`](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-retry) which takes a number which is the maximum retries to do before an error is emitted.

Comment: @jnes..this is not working ...getStatuses() is not called..I tried with retry too..I updated the question

Comment: the observable from refreshToken never completes. Either add `observer.complete()` after updating storage or add .take(1) before .concat()